# Kafka-node Consumer Message Push to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, apache-kafka, array-push

I have started learning javascript.

I have a code from example :

```
Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
client = new kafka.KafkaClient();

module.exports = topic => {
  consumer = new Consumer(client, [{ topic: topic, partition: 0 }], {
    autoCommit: false
  });
  var Datas = [];
  consumer.on("message", function(message) {
    Datas.push(message);
  });

  console.log(Datas); //return = []
};
```

Why the message data is not pushed to array?

Comment: move `console.log` inside `consumer.on("message", ...` and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

`Datas.push(message);` is happening inside the listener which is asynchronous while the console statement is executed immeditaley. That is why it is empty array. You can either register `end` listener if there is any and do console in that or move the console inside the on message listener.